# Simplest suggestion box (like google suggestion when you using search) in PHP (without jQuery)

Tags: search

I can't find simple solution for suggestion in php/java script (no jQuery or something) so would like if some have some advice?

It is simple, when people search my site I want they to see suggestions, I made everything for 'feeding' that box, but can't code or find somewhere simple php/java script only solution, so please give me some useful link or code.

Also, forgot to say that I found "XMLHttpRequest" and made implementation which works great, but since I never ever used XMLHttpRequest I am not sure will it work all platforms and browsers? I tested in few (IE,F,Chorme,Safary) and it works on windows platform, but not sure will it work on other (Mobile platform for example) that XMLHttpRequest solution?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the below link to find an awesome  auto complete script without using any kind of javascript frameworks like jQuery or Prototype. Probably this might be the thing you are looking for.

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/index.shtml

> UPDATE
>
> Giving some extra links below you can find similar auto complete or
>   auto search without jQuery
>
> http://www.brandspankingnew.net/specials/ajax_autosuggest/ajax_autosuggest_autocomplete.html
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8020/Auto-complete-Control
>
> http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/12/creating_a_google_suggest_styl.html
>
> http://www.devthought.com/2008/01/12/textboxlist-meets-autocompletion/
>
> http://wick.sourceforge.net/